# Reducing $(\frac1{2^0}-\frac1{2^1})+2(\frac1{2^1}-\frac1{2^2})+\cdots+n(\frac1{2^{n-1}}-\frac1{2^n})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How to reduce this sum?
> $$\left(\frac1{2^0}-\frac1{2^1}\right)+2\left(\frac1{2^1}-\frac1{2^2}\right)+\cdots+(n-1)\left(\frac1{2^{n-2}}-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)+n\left(\frac1{2^{n-1}}-\frac1{2^n}\right) $$

I tried to cancel the terms like a telescoping series, but I couldn't do it. So, does someone have an idea to what to do here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Is the second term a typo ? I do not think that telescoping works here, but you can use $$\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2^n}$$ for every positive integer $n$

Comment: yes second one is typo it should be 2(1/2 - 1/(2^2)). But for the hint you gave me, how would i use it? do you have an idea?

Comment: The hint allows to reduce the sum to $$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{2^j}$$ I do not know which techniques you are allowed to use to find an explicite formula for this sum , or maybe this is already the desired result. This is the reason why we need more context to give an answer fitting to your level.

Comment: From the hint suggested by @Peter, it would turn out to be a simple arithmetico-geometric series

Comment: @Peter thank you, i guess the answer given is like what you think, also thanks :)

Comment: @datboi thanks man appreciate it

Comment: @blue thanks mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general term is $$n\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)=n\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-n\frac{1}{2^{n}}=\left(\frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}-\frac{n}{2^{n}}\right)+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$

Now can you see the telescoping pattern?. Only the term in the parantheses telescopes. The other is just a simple sum of a geometric progression. You can do that using geometric series formula.

Comment: Excellent, I always used more complicated techniques for this sum , but never have seen this approach (+1) ! Now I understand why the sum is written in a seemingly more complicated way.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron thanks a lot

Comment: No problem !!!!